# How can I deploy / serve a react-based excel office addin?

Tags: excel, office-js

I am writing an office addin using office-js with React. My addin sideloads and works alright but I'm running into issues deploying it.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a trial react app (addin) using the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react and https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office.
- Sideload the addinusing npm start and everything works well when served via the dev server -- everything works well!
- Try serving the add-in statically in one of the two ways (I made sure the manifest is updated appropriately):

HTTP: `npm install -g serve` and then `serve -s dist`

or

HTTPS using a server like express:

```
   express = require("express");
    https = require("https");

    const PORT = 3000;
    const SERVER_ROOT = "dist";
    var fs = require('fs');

    var server=express();

    var staticOptions = {
        dotfiles: 'ignore',
        etag: false,
        extensions: ['htm', 'html'],
        index: false,
        maxAge: '1d',
        redirect: false,
        setHeaders: function (res, path, stat) {
          res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now())
        }
      }
      server.use(express.static(SERVER_ROOT, staticOptions));

      var sslOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/server.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/server.crt')
      };

      https.createServer(sslOptions, server).listen(PORT, function(){
          console.log("Server started.");
          console.log("Listening on port:" + PORT);
      });
```

4. On loading the add-in, the task pane is blank.
5. Firing up a debugger or the F12 IE Chooser tool throws the exception:

> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Office.js has not fully loaded.
>   Your app must call "Office.onReady()" as part of it's loading sequence
>   (or set the "Office.initialize" function). If your app has this
>   functionality, try reloading this page.

6.Opening the html page on a web browser complains that React and ReactDOM are undefined (happens in index.tsx, but I think eventually the modules get loaded) and then subsequently throws the same exception "Office.js is not fully loaded".

-- In case it helps, I'm using react 16.2.0 and I'm on Office 365 desktop, version 1807, build 10325 (monthly channel).

-- Also, is there a way to avoid hosting on a server and just using a manifest (in a shared folder) pointing to another shared folder? I'm thinking browserify or something similar (but browserify didnt work either and I guess webpack might be the reason). [I did see the documentation about deploying addins, but they are not very helpful in this case].

Comment: Could you add some details to your description of step 3? Where are you hosting the HTML/JS files? How are you deploying the manifest and sideloading?

Comment: @RickKirkham Done, hope it helps.

Comment: How are you deploying the manifest and sideloading it? Also, in the manifest, what is the value of the SourceLocation? Have you made any changes in the line that calls Office.initialize?

Comment: @RickKirkham I made no changes at all to the scaffolded project. I just copied the manifest to a shared folder on my own computer and use `npm run start` for sideloading for dev and that works just fine (this deploys to webpack-dev at https://localhost:3000/index.html).  For deployment, I use the same manifest when I deploy it via HTTPS. For Http, I just tried changing the https://localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3000 and start the server with -p 3000.

Comment: For some reason, SO truncated the protocol part of the url; I meant `https://localhost:3000` to `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not clear on how you are sideloading. You say that you put the manifest in a shared folder. Did you follow all of the steps in this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Comment: @RickKirkham, yes, that's what I did. Like I said, I am able to sideload when I do `npm start`, so that says I did the sideloading right. I just can't get it to work when I do `npm run build` and then serve the dist folder on an express server (as in the script above).

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to do this to deploy the add-in on my own server. But I can't even get it to work with localhost.

Comment: Ok, Removing the uglify in the webpack.prod.config helped me with this issue. I don't still know what the exact about it the issue is, but atleast I have been able to narrow it down.